# Eclipse doesn't take chanegs into account, have to rebuild manually

Tags: eclipse, build

I am running Unit Tests on some code, and discovering a few errors. The problem I am facing is that when I change the code, the tests results are not changing unless I manually run Maven to rebuild the project. Any change to my code is only effective after a manual rebuild.

Just for trying, I wrote a dummy test class:

```
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void testTest () {
        assertEquals(0,0);
    }
}
```

At first, Eclipse was not detecting any test, ending after 0 seconds and zero tests. After rebuilding, it was working. I then changed the line to `assertEquals(0,1)`, and had to rebuild again for the test to fail.

I tried to reinstall Eclipse completly, but it did not fix the problem. I have no idea of what could be causing it.

Comment: Do you have the maven integration plug-ins for Eclipse, m2e, installed?

Comment: _"I am running Unit Tests"_ does not say which way you choose to do this and also your project structure is unknown. Provide detailed step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce your problem and show your `pom.xml`.